# Using a QComboBox to Edit a ForeignKey in a QAbstractTableModel referencing another QAbstractTableModel

Tags: qt, view, combobox, model, qcombobox

I'm currently programming an application in Qt using the Model/View architecture and I now ran into a problem that I haven't found a solution to so far.

The problem:
I've got 2 `AbstractTableModels`: a `Customer Model` and a `Country Model`.
Both of these `Models` have an `Id` field, filled with a GUID and some other fields storing information about them.

The `Customer Model` also has a `Country_ID` field that stores a reference to a `Record` in the `Country Model`. Just like a Foreign Key in SQL.

Now, I want to use a `QCombobox` to "Edit this Field" in my application.
So I set the `Model` of my `Combobox` to the `Country Model` and used a `QDataWidgetMapper` to connect this `Combobox` to the `Customer Model`.
This works absolutely fine as long as the `ComboBox` is displaying the `ID` field of the Country Model.
But I need to display the `Name` of the `Country` instead of the `ID`.

On my search for a solution, I found [this page](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq21-datawidgetmapper.html) which nearly solved my problem. (section "Using Delegates to Offer Choices").
But there, they make the assumption that the `Id` field matches the `currentIndex` of the `Combobox`, which doesn't work in my case since the `ID` fields are GUIDs.

I'm a bit at loss on how to solve this problem. Can I solve it by using a `Delegate` or can I somehow connect the `Customer Model` with the `Country Model` or should I use a different `Modeltype` for the `Country Model`?

Since I'm rather new to this language, any help would be appreciated.